# How to design a mock comments section?

Tags: javascript

> For this challenge, you are going to build a mock comments section.
> Design
>
> We're going to focus on two aspects:
>
> Users
>
> Users come in 3 flavors, normal users, moderators, and admins. Normal users can only create new comments, and edit the their own
> comments. Moderators have the added ability to delete comments (to
> remove trolls), while admins have the ability to edit or delete any
> comment.
> Users can log in and out, and we track when they last logged in
>
> Comments
>
> Comments are simply a message, a timestamp, and the author.
> Comments can also be a reply, so we'll store what the parent comment was.

Beneath is my code:

```
class Admin extends Moderator {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
  canEdit(comment) {
    return true;
  }
}

class Comment {
  constructor(author, message, repliedTo) {
    this.createdAt = new Date();
    this._author = author;
    this._message = message;
    this.repliedTo = repliedTo || null;
  }
  getMessage() {
    return this._message;
  }
  setMessage(message) {
    this._message = message;
  }
  getCreatedAt() {
    return this.createdAt;
  }
  getAuthor() {
    return this._author;
  }
  getRepliedTo() {
    return this.repliedTo;
  }
  getString(comment) {
    const authorName = comment.getAuthor().getName();
    if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;
    return `${comment.getMessage()} by ${authorName} (replied to ${this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())})`;
  }
  toString() {
    const authorName = this.getAuthor().getName();
    if (!this.getRepliedTo()) {
      return `${this._message} by ${authorName}`;
    }
    return this.getString(this);
  }
}
```

I get the error

> The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (nested reply)

Answer (score 4):

Although this supposed to be an assignment, the [question](https://repl.it/@DotunAkolade/Object-Oriented-Tests) was a bit technical and unclear; this's the proven solution

```
class User {
  constructor(name) {
   this._name = name;
   this._loggedIn = false;
   this._lastLoggedInAt = null;
  }
  isLoggedIn() {
    return this._loggedIn;
  }
  getLastLoggedInAt() {
    return this._lastLoggedInAt;
  }
  logIn() {
    this._lastLoggedInAt = new Date();
    this._loggedIn = true;
  }
  logOut() {
    this._loggedIn = false
  }
  getName() {
    return this._name;
  }
  setName(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }
  canEdit(comment) {
    if(comment._author._name === this._name) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  canDelete(comment) {
    return false;
  }
}

class Moderator extends User {
   constructor(name) {
     super(name);
   }
   canDelete(comment) {
     return true;
   }
}

class Admin extends Moderator {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name)
  }
  canEdit(comment) {
    return true;
  }
}

class Comment {
   constructor(author = null, message, repliedTo = null) {
     this._createdAt = new Date();
     this._message = message;
     this._repliedTo = repliedTo;
     this._author = author;
   }
   getMessage() {
     return this._message;
   }
   setMessage(message) {
     this._message = message;
   }
   getCreatedAt() {
     return this._createdAt;
   }
   getAuthor() {
     return this._author;
   }
   getRepliedTo() {
     return this._repliedTo;
   }
   toString() {
     if(this._repliedTo === null) {
        return this._message + " by " + this._author._name
     }
     return this._message + " by " + this._author._name + " (replied to " + 
          this._repliedTo._author._name + ")"
   }
 }
```

The error was because you were calling a `getName()` method on `getAuthor` method which wasn't available. You can get author name directly from Comment `this._author._name`.

Answer (score 0):

I make use of JavaScript constructor coding style, to write this solution but it should not matter much as the solution does not need you to change your style. Observe that the fields (_author, _message, _repliedTo) are private, and private fields can only be accessed through public methods. And that is basically what I did here in the toString() method.

```js
function Comment(author, message, repliedTo = null) {
  var _author = author;
  var _message = message;
  var _repliedTo = repliedTo;
  
  
  this.getAuthor = function() {
    return _author;
  };
  
  this.getRepliedTo = function() {
    return _repliedTo;
  };
  
  this.toString = function() {
    return ((_repliedTo === null) ? message + " by " + _author.getName() : message + " by " + _author.getName() + " (replied to " + this.getRepliedTo().getAuthor().getName() + ")");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the getString() method...

```
toString() 
{
    return ((this._repliedTo === null) ? this._message + " by " + 
           this._author.getName() : this._message + " by " + 
           this._author.getName() + " (replied to " + this._repliedTo._author.getName() + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {
  function __construct($name) {
   private $name;
   private $loggedIn;
   private $lastLoggedInAt;

   $this->name = $name;
   $this->loggedIn = false;
   $this->lastLoggedInAt = null;
  }
  function isLoggedIn() {
    return $this->loggedIn;
  }
  function getLastLoggedInAt() {
    return $this->lastLoggedInAt;
  }
  function logIn() {
    $this->lastLoggedInAt = new Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->loggedIn = true;
  }
  function logOut() {
    $this->loggedIn = false;
  }
  function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
  function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  function canEdit($comment) {
    if($comment->author->name === $this->name) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  function canDelete($comment) {
    return false;
  }
}

class Moderator extends User {
   function __construct($name) {
     $this->name = $name;
   }
   function canDelete($comment) {
     return true;
   }
}

class Admin extends Moderator {
  function constructor($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  function canEdit($comment) {
    return true;
  }
}

class Comment {
   function __construct($author = null, $message, $repliedTo = null) {

    private $createdAt;
    private $message;
    private $repliedTo;
    private $author;

     $this->createdAt = new Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     $this->message = $message;
     $this->repliedTo = $repliedTo;
     $this->author = $author;
   }
   function getMessage() {
     return $this->message;
   }
   function setMessage($message) {
     $this->message = $message;
   }
   function getCreatedAt() {
     return $this->createdAt;
   }
   function getAuthor() {
     return $this->author;
   }
   function getRepliedTo() {
     return $this->repliedTo;
   }
   function __toString() {
     if($this->repliedTo === null) {
        return $this->message + " by " + $this->author->name;
     }
     return $this->message + " by " + $this->author->name + " (replied to " + 
          $this->repliedTo->author->name + ")";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java version if anyone needs:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Solution {
  public static class User {
    String name;
    boolean loggedIn;
    Date lastLoggedInAt;
    
    public User(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
      this.lastLoggedInAt = lastLoggedInAt;
    }
    
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
      return this.loggedIn;
    }
    
    public Date getLastLoggedInAt() {
      return this.lastLoggedInAt;
    }
    
    public void logIn() {
      this.lastLoggedInAt = new Date();
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }
    
    public void logOut() {
      this.loggedIn = false;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
    
    public boolean canEdit(Comment comment) {
      if(comment.getAuthor().name == this.name) {
      return true;
    }
      return false;
    }
    
    public boolean canDelete(Comment comment) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static class Moderator extends User{
    public Moderator(String name) {
      super(name);
    }
    
    public boolean canDelete(Comment comment) {
     return true;
   }
  }

  public static class Admin extends Moderator{
    public Admin(String name) {
       super(name);
    }
    
     public boolean canEdit(Comment comment) {
     return true;
   }
  }
  
  public static class Comment {
    User author;
    //注意下面也要是author
    String message;
    Comment comment;
    Date createdAt;
    Comment repliedTo;
    
    public Comment(User author, String message) {
      this.author = author;
      this.message = message;
    }
    
    public Comment(User author, String message, Comment repliedTo) {
      this.author = author;
      this.message = message;
      this.repliedTo = repliedTo;
    }
    
    public String getMessage() {
      return this.message;
    }
    
    public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
    
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
      return this.createdAt;
    }
    
    public User getAuthor() {
      return this.author;
    }
    
    public Comment getRepliedTo() {
      return this.repliedTo;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
      if(this.repliedTo == null) {
        return this.message + " by " + this.author.getName();
     }
     return this.message + " by " + this.author.getName() + " (replied to " + 
          this.repliedTo.getAuthor().name + ")";
   }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This question is tagged [`javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), why would anyone need this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Answers provided above won't pass basic unit tests for this assignment. Here's an option I successfully submitted to complete the challenge:

```
export class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
    this._lastLoginDate = null;
    this._loggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this._loggedIn;
  }

  getLastLoggedInAt() {
    return this._lastLoginDate;
  }

  logIn() {
    this._lastLoginDate = new Date();
    return Promise.resolve('Success').then(() => {
      this._loggedIn = true;
    });
  }

  logOut() {
    this._loggedIn = false;
  }

  getName() {
    return this._name;
  }

  setName(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  canEdit(comment) {
    if (comment.getAuthor().getName() === this.getName()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  canDelete(comment) {
    return false;
  }
}

export class Moderator extends User {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  canDelete(comment) {
    return true;
  }
}

export class Admin extends Moderator {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  canEdit(comment) {
    return true;
  }
}

export class Comment {
  constructor(author, message, repliedTo = null) {
    this._author = author;
    this._message = message;
    this._repliedTo = repliedTo || null;
    this._createdAt = new Date();
  }

  getMessage() {
    return this._message;
  }

  setMessage(message) {
    this._message = message;
  }

  getCreatedAt() {
    return this._createdAt;
  }

  getAuthor() {
    return this._author;
  }

  getRepliedTo() {
    return this._repliedTo;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.getRepliedTo() === null
      ? `${this.getMessage()} by ${this.getAuthor().getName()}`
      : `${this.getMessage()} by ${this.getAuthor().getName()} (replied to ${this.getRepliedTo()
          .getAuthor()
          .getName()})`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why they will not pass unit test ? Can you add explaination in your answer thanks to [edit] ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this thing using typescript:

```
export class User {
  private _name: string;
  private _loggedIn: boolean;
  private _lastLoggedInAt: Date | null;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    this._loggedIn = false;
    this._lastLoggedInAt = null;
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this._loggedIn;
  }

  getLastLoggedInAt(): Date | null {
    return this._lastLoggedInAt;
  }

  async logIn(): Promise<void> {
    this._lastLoggedInAt = new Date();
    await Promise.resolve("suceess");
    this._loggedIn = true;
  }

  logOut(): void {
    this._loggedIn = false;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  setName(name: string): void {
    this._name = name;
  }

  canEdit(comment: Comment): boolean {
    if (comment.getAuthor().getName() === this._name) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  canDelete(comment: Comment): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}

export class Moderator extends User {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
  canDelete(_comment: Comment): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

export class Admin extends Moderator {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
  canEdit(_comment: Comment): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

export class Comment {
  private _author: User;
  private _message: string;
  private _repliedTo?: Comment | null;
  private _createdAt: Date;
  constructor(author: User, message: string, repliedTo?: Comment) {
    this._author = author;
    this._message = message;
    this._repliedTo = repliedTo;
    this._createdAt = new Date();
  }

  getMessage(): string {
    return this._message;
  }

  setMessage(message: string): void {
    this._message = message;
  }

  getCreatedAt(): Date {
    return this._createdAt;
  }

  getAuthor(): User {
    return this._author;
  }

  getRepliedTo(): Comment | null {
    if (this._repliedTo) {
      return this._repliedTo;
    }
    return null;
  }

  toString(): string {
    if (this.getRepliedTo()) {
      return `${this.getMessage()} by ${this.getAuthor().getName()} (replied to ${this._repliedTo
        ?.getAuthor()
        .getName()})`;
    }
    return `${this.getMessage()} by ${this.getAuthor().getName()}`;
  }
}
```

and few unit tests using Jest

```
describe('Normal user tests', function() {
  it('should return name of the User', () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    expect(user.getName()).toEqual('User 1');
  });
  
  it('shoud return isLoggedIn as true when logIn method is called' , () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    user.logIn().then(() => {
    expect(user.isLoggedIn()).toBeTruthy();
  }).catch((error) => {
        expect(user.isLoggedIn()).toBe(false);
    });;
 });

 it('shoud return _lastLoggedInAt as the date when logIn method is called' , () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    user.logIn().then(() => {
    expect(user.getLastLoggedInAt()).toBe(new Date());
  })
 });
    
 it('shoud return _loggedIn as false when logOut method is called', () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    user.logOut();
    expect(user.isLoggedIn()).toBe(false);
 });
     
  it('shoud setName of the user' , () => {
    const user = new User("User");
    user.setName("User 2");
    expect(user.getName()).toEqual('User 2');
  });
});

describe('Moderator user tests', function() {
  it('should return name of the User', () => {
    const moderator = new Moderator("Moderator 1");
    const message = "Hello there"
    const comment = new Comment (moderator, message);
    expect(moderator.canDelete(comment)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

describe('Admin user tests', function() {
  it('should return name of the User', () => {
    const admin = new Admin("Admin 1");
    const message = "Hello there"
    const comment = new Comment (admin, message);
    expect(admin.canEdit(comment)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


describe('Comment tests', function() {
  it('should return message of the author', () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    const message = "Hi! This is my message."
    const comment = new Comment (user, message)
    expect(comment.getMessage()).toEqual(message);
  });
  
 it('should set new message', () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    const message = "Hi! This is my message."
    const newMessage = "Hi! This is new message."
    const comment = new Comment (user, message);
    comment.setMessage(newMessage)
    expect(comment.getMessage()).toEqual(newMessage);
  });
  
 it('should return null when replied to does not exists', () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    const message = "Hi! This is my message."
    const comment = new Comment (user, message);
    expect(comment.getRepliedTo()).toBe(null);
  });
  
  it('should return repliedTo when replied to exists', () => {
    const user = new User("User 1");
    const message = "Hi! This is my message."
    
    const repliedToUser = new User("User 2");
    const repliedToMessage = "Hi! This is my replied message.";
    const repliedToComment = new Comment (repliedToUser, repliedToMessage);
    const comment = new Comment (user, message, repliedToComment);

    expect(comment.getRepliedTo()).toBe(repliedToComment);
  });
  
  it('should return repliedTo string message when replied to exists', () => {
    const user = new User("User1");
    const message = "Hello there"
    
    const repliedToUser = new User("User2");
    const repliedToMessage = "Hi! This is my replied message.";
    const repliedToComment = new Comment (repliedToUser, repliedToMessage);
    const comment = new Comment (user, message, repliedToComment);

    expect(comment.toString()).toBe("Hello there by User1 (replied to User2)");
  });
  
  it('should return comment string message when replied to does not exists', () => {
    const user = new User("User1");
    const message = "Hello there"
    const comment = new Comment (user, message);

    expect(comment.toString()).toBe("Hello there by User1");
  });
  
});
```